# Install new module in Anaconda: Keyerror('pkgs_dirs',)

Tags: python, module, installation

While installing any new Module in anaconda(eg. teradata) I am getting the below error:

```
environment variables:
conda info could not be constructed. KeyError('pkgs_dirs',)
```

Is there any solution for this please ? I have Teradata 13 in my system and Python version is 3.4.

I am able to establish a connection using `pyodbc.connect` but not able to install the teradata module into the conda environment. Only after I do this can I run queries to fetch my data set.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just to clarify, this isn't specific to the Teradata module, but rather any Module in anaconda?

Comment: Yes this if for any module. whenever i give "conda install <Modulename> it just throws this error!!!

Comment: The documentation mentions `pkgs_dirs` here: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-package-directories-pkgs-dirs

Comment: @AswathManickavasagan are you still getting this error? This is on Windows isn't it?  Do you also get it when running `conda update anaconda`?

Answer (score 3):

run "conda info" and "conda config --show-sources" locate where the .condarc files are located.  These files configure shell behaviors.  You can add entries to these files via this command:

`conda config --file C:\Users\username\.condarc --add pkgs_dirs C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs`

*you can add multiple entries

Comment: If you don't have a `.condarc` file in your home dir, run `conda config --add channels conda-forge` to create one.

Answer (score 1):

I tried following commands in Windows PowerShell

```
pip install pywin32==300

conda config --file C:\Users\username\.condarc --add pkgs_dirs C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs
```

problem with pywin32 version, so changed it to 300.