# Fresh install of conda not working due to "KeyError('pkgs_dirs')" and missing DLLs

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I installed a fresh new version of Miniconda, but no matter what i try to do ([Install new module in Anaconda: Keyerror('pkgs_dirs',)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54087577/install-new-module-in-anaconda-keyerrorpkgs-dirs), [Download error for us package (KeyError: 'pkgs_dirs')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72165144/download-error-for-us-package-keyerror-pkgs-dirs), [Change conda default pkgs_dirs and envs dirs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57416542/change-conda-default-pkgs-dirs-and-envs-dirs)) installing packages or reading conda info doesn't seem to work.

An exception is thrown when trying to run, for example `conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit=10.1`. New installations (as this is a fresh installation) are not helping either. All commands are being run from Miniconda terminal on Windows 10, and MS Redistributables have been installed with default settings (and the system has been rebooted). I was not able to see which DLLs are missing, as the only one I'm able to see with my single brain cell is "shell". I have followed the installation instructions from https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows.

.condarc file contents are as follow:

```
envs_dirs:
  - 'C:\Users\matti\.conda\envs'
pkgs_dirs:
  - 'C:\Users\matti\.conda\pkgs'
```

The envs directory does not exist but the pkgs directory exists. As such I've also tried to create the directory "envs" with no success

Error thrown when trying to install package:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed
WARNING conda.exceptions:print_unexpected_error_report(1216): KeyError('pkgs_dirs')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1082, in __call__
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 87, in _main
exit_code = do_call(args, p)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 84, in do_call
return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 20, in execute
install(args, parser, 'install')
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 260, in install
unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 152, in solve_for_transaction
unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(update_modifier, deps_modifier,
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 195, in solve_for_diff
final_precs = self.solve_final_state(update_modifier, deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned,
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 300, in solve_final_state
ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 88, in decorated
return f(*args, **kwds)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 463, in _collect_all_metadata
index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 1058, in _prepare
reduced_index = get_reduced_index(self.prefix, self.channels,
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 288, in get_reduced_index
new_records = SubdirData.query_all(spec, channels=channels, subdirs=subdirs,
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 140, in query_all
result = tuple(concat(executor.map(subdir_query, channel_urls)))
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 609, in result_iterator
yield fs.pop().result()
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 446, in result
return self.__get_result()
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 391, in __get_result
raise self._exception
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 132, in <lambda>
subdir_query = lambda url: tuple(SubdirData(Channel(url), repodata_fn=repodata_fn).query(
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 145, in query
self.load()
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 210, in load
_internal_state = self._load()
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 375, in _load
raw_repodata_str = fetch_repodata_remote_request(
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 701, in fetch_repodata_remote_request
resp = session.get(join_url(url, filename), headers=headers, proxies=session.proxies,
File "C:\Users\matti\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\matti\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 528, in request
prep = self.prepare_request(req)
File "C:\Users\matti\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in prepare_request
p.prepare(
File "C:\Users\matti\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 320, in prepare
self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
File "C:\Users\matti\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 551, in prepare_auth
r = auth(self)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\session.py", line 110, in __call__
request.url = CondaHttpAuth.add_binstar_token(request.url)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\session.py", line 134, in add_binstar_token
for binstar_url, token in iteritems(read_binstar_tokens()):
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\anaconda_client.py", line 35, in read_binstar_tokens
token_dir = _get_binstar_token_directory()
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\anaconda_client.py", line 30, in _get_binstar_token_directory
return AppDirs('binstar', 'ContinuumIO').user_data_dir
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 245, in user_data_dir
return user_data_dir(self.appname, self.appauthor,
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 67, in user_data_dir
path = os.path.join(_get_win_folder(const), appauthor, appname)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 284, in _get_win_folder_with_pywin32
from win32com.shell import shellcon, shell
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing shell: The specified procedure could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1214, in print_unexpected_error_report
message_builder.append(get_main_info_str(error_report['conda_info']))
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 237, in get_main_info_str
info_dict['_' + key] = ('\n' + 26 * ' ').join(info_dict[key])
KeyError: 'pkgs_dirs'

           # >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1082, in __call__
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 87, in _main
exit_code = do_call(args, p)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 84, in do_call
return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 20, in execute
install(args, parser, 'install')
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 260, in install
unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 152, in solve_for_transaction
unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(update_modifier, deps_modifier,
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 195, in solve_for_diff
final_precs = self.solve_final_state(update_modifier, deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned,
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 300, in solve_final_state
ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 88, in decorated
return f(*args, **kwds)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 463, in _collect_all_metadata
index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 1058, in _prepare
reduced_index = get_reduced_index(self.prefix, self.channels,
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 288, in get_reduced_index
new_records = SubdirData.query_all(spec, channels=channels, subdirs=subdirs,
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 140, in query_all
result = tuple(concat(executor.map(subdir_query, channel_urls)))
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 609, in result_iterator
yield fs.pop().result()
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 446, in result
return self.__get_result()
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 391, in __get_result
raise self._exception
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 132, in <lambda>
subdir_query = lambda url: tuple(SubdirData(Channel(url), repodata_fn=repodata_fn).query(
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 145, in query
self.load()
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 210, in load
_internal_state = self._load()
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 375, in _load
raw_repodata_str = fetch_repodata_remote_request(
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 701, in fetch_repodata_remote_request
resp = session.get(join_url(url, filename), headers=headers, proxies=session.proxies,
File "C:\Users\matti\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\matti\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 528, in request
prep = self.prepare_request(req)
File "C:\Users\matti\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in prepare_request
p.prepare(
File "C:\Users\matti\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 320, in prepare
self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
File "C:\Users\matti\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 551, in prepare_auth
r = auth(self)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\session.py", line 110, in __call__
request.url = CondaHttpAuth.add_binstar_token(request.url)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\session.py", line 134, in add_binstar_token
for binstar_url, token in iteritems(read_binstar_tokens()):
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\anaconda_client.py", line 35, in read_binstar_tokens
token_dir = _get_binstar_token_directory()
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\anaconda_client.py", line 30, in _get_binstar_token_directory
return AppDirs('binstar', 'ContinuumIO').user_data_dir
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 245, in user_data_dir
return user_data_dir(self.appname, self.appauthor,
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 67, in user_data_dir
path = os.path.join(_get_win_folder(const), appauthor, appname)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 284, in _get_win_folder_with_pywin32
from win32com.shell import shellcon, shell
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing shell: The specified procedure could not be found.

`$ C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py install -c anaconda cudatoolkit=10.1`

environment variables:
conda info could not be constructed.
KeyError('pkgs_dirs')
```

Many places seem to mention that running `conda info` would somehow help, but even that throws an error:

```
# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1082, in __call__
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 87, in _main
exit_code = do_call(args, p)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 84, in do_call
return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 317, in execute
info_dict = get_info_dict(args.system)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 164, in get_info_dict
envs_dirs=context.envs_dirs,
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 517, in envs_dirs
return mockable_context_envs_dirs(self.root_writable, self.root_prefix, self._envs_dirs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 91, in mockable_context_envs_dirs
fixed_dirs += join(user_data_dir(APP_NAME, APP_NAME), 'envs'),
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 67, in user_data_dir
path = os.path.join(_get_win_folder(const), appauthor, appname)
File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 284, in _get_win_folder_with_pywin32
from win32com.shell import shellcon, shell
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing shell: The specified procedure could not be found.
`$ C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py info`
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a bit late but this error on windows should be related to the pywin32 package. A solution is to reinstall this package. You could do this running this command from your base environment:

```
conda install -n name-your-environment -c anaconda pywin32
```

Answer (score 0):

in case the env variable "subdirs" has not been set in the local .condarc file,
this error might also pop up.

add to , or create, .condarc file for that active env, with:
*subdirs:

- win-64 (for windows)*

this is a temp. workaround for several bugs, inc. pywin32 and conda not recogniz side env on win. it seems this cluster of bugs are forming a funnel, some of which are tracing back at least 2 years.

note that installing TF by  pip is only decent after a complete conda/mamba envir installation for tf use.